# How to calculate amount of memory needed for Solr

Tags: linux, vmware-esx, solr

I run solr application on a VM with 41G of memory and I saw that the solr consumme a big amount of memory.
I appended 16G to the VM in spite of that solr consumme all memory available in 30min. My question is that surely there are a tuning needed please what is it and how can I calculate the memory needed for Solr node ?

Comment: http://lucidworks.com/blog/2011/09/14/estimating-memory-and-storage-for-lucenesolr/